# MySQL GROUP BY query group results by week, month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named "counter" that has 3 fields:

```
| Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| record | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| passed | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My table records

```
mysql> SELECT record, passed FROM counter;
+---------------------+--------+
| record              | passed |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2019-09-19 00:00:00 |      1 |
```

I would like to make a query to group the results by weeks, and months from the field record.

I have tried to do it like this but doesn't look right

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(record, '%d-%m-%Y') AS ts, COUNT(*) FROM counter WHERE record >= '2019-10-09' AND   record <  '2019-10-09' + INTERVAL 7 DAY GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(record, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Comment: If you don't want to retrieve data by time, just use Date type for record field. It's easy.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple grouping with date extraction must work

```
select 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM record) V_YEAR,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM record) V_MONTH,
    EXTRACT(WEEK FROM record) V_WEEK,
    COUNT(*)
FROM COUNTER
GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM record) ,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM record) ,
    EXTRACT(WEEK FROM record)
```

edit same works with `DATE_FORMAT(date, format)` as well

```
select 
    DATE_FORMAT(record, '%Y') V_YEAR,
    DATE_FORMAT(record, '%M') V_MONTH,
    DATE_FORMAT(record, '%d') V_WEEK,
    COUNT(*)
FROM COUNTER
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(record, '%Y') ,
    DATE_FORMAT(record, '%M') ,
    DATE_FORMAT(record, '%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of passes, fails etc per week:

```
SELECT week(record_date) as weekofyear, sum(passed) as numpasses, count(*) - sum(passed) as numfails, count(*) as total
FROM counter
WHERE record_date >= '2019-01-01' and record_date < '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY week(record_date)
```

Swap week for month etc

MySQL supports ROLLUP which can summarise weeks and months in the same statement:

```
SELECT month(record_date) as monthofyear, week(record_date) as weekofyear, sum(passed) as numpasses, count(*) - sum(passed) as numfails, count(*) as total
FROM counter
WHERE record_date >= '2019-01-01' and record_date < '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY month(record_date), week(record_date) WITH ROLLUP
```

lines where the week is null are the total for the month

Comment: Please note that where clause cannot use index if there is any. instead it is better to use use record_date between from_date and to_date

Comment: I personally wouldn't expect an index on datetime because it's too selective to be useful. MySQL now supports functional indexes I believe, so indexing the year/similar broad time period  might make sense if this query will experience heavy use. I've swapped it out anyway, but this wasn't what the question was about

Comment: passed colum has only 1 (one). It is only boolean accounted events. So there is no "fails".

Comment: Why store it at all then? There's no point having a column if all it ever contains is 1. In the absence of any detail in your question, assuming that it contains 0 or 1 isn't an unreasonable assumption to make; perhaps consider providing more detail next time